# Struct prototype before the main()

Tags: c, struct, prototype

Having a `struct` -

`typedef struct Point{
    ....
}`

I want to write its `prototype` before the `main()` , something like  -

```
typedef struct Point  ;

int main() {
    Point p1 ,p2 ; 
    ... 
}

typedef struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
} Point;
```

The above gives me error - `unknown type name 'Point'` .

How could I achieve that right  ?

**Edit:**

I know that it would be work if I define to `struct` before the `main()` . I just want to know whether it have any `prototye` similarly to `function prototye`.

Comment: Your usage of the word prototype is incorrect. Prototypes only concern functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration:

```
typedef struct Point;
```

is not valid in C.

> How could I achieve that right ?

```
typedef struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
} Point;

int main() {
    Point p1 ,p2 ; 
}
```

You cannot achieve the same with `struct Point` declaration after `main` because the implementation has to know the storage of `Point` objects `p1` and `p2` when you declare them in `main`.

Comment: So you say it isn't possible to use the `struct` until it completely defined   ?

Comment: @URL see my addition at the end of the answer: no, you cannot. You could do it if you declared pointers to `Point` in `main` but this is not your case.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this, because the C language is organized around one pass compilation. At the point where a type name is used to declare or define something, that type have been previously declared.

There is a relaxation of this rule, namely: you can define *incomplete types* in C. However, incomplete types cannot be used to define objects: at least, not certain kinds of objects. So this is invalid:

```
struct foo;  /* introduces incomplete type foo */

struct foo x; /* incomplete type for external definition is okay, as long
                 as the type is completed before the end of the translation unit. */

extern struct foo e; /* incomplete type for external declaration is allowed even if
                        the type is not completely known in this translation unit
                        at all. A definition of the object e must exist somewhere
                        in the linked program---unless e is not used; then a definition
                        need not exist at all. */

void func(void)
{
   struct foo y; /* incomplete type not okay here */
}

struct bar {
   struct foo z; /* not okay here */
};

struct foo {
   char *s;
};  /* struct foo is now a complete type, but it's too late in the file */
```

The last declaration above, which completes the type `struct foo` allows for the `struct foo x;` definition to be valid.  So there is some "lexically retroactive" action in the C type system; it's just not general.

The situations marked as "not okay" require the struct type to be complete at that point in the source code.

**If you want to define local variables of type `Point` in your `main` function, that type must be declared and complete prior to that function. If that type is not complete, you can still define variables of type `Point *`: pointer to `Point`. But these pointers cannot be dereferenced.**

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to do that because the compiler would need to know how much space to allocate for Point when you allocate it.  Prototyping wouldn't give you this information.

You could do this, as the size of the pointer will be known:

```
typedef struct Point Point;

int main() {
    Point * p1;
}

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

I don't know if that will meet your needs, though

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring your struct after `main`.

```
typedef struct Point  ; // you dont really need this. 

typedef struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
} Point;

int main() {
    Point p1 ,p2 ; 
    ... 
}
```

even better is this:

```
typedef struct Point {
   int x;
   int y;
} Point;

int main() {
    Point p1 ,p2 ; 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the declaration in another file (e.g., `Point.h`) that gets included at the top of your `main()` file, and put the *definition* in a separately-compiled implementation file (e.g., `Point.cpp`).